# why is <[^>]*> not working as regex

Tags: java, regex

i am trying to get

```
<hello@yellow.com>
```

from

```
asdasdasdasdasdadasdsad<hello@yellow.com>asdasdasdasdasd
```

from the following method:

```
private String extractInvalidEmailAddress(String message) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<[^>]*>");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(message);
    matcher.find();
    message = matcher.group();

    return message;
}
```

But all I am getting is `null`! What do I have to do to get `hello@yellow.com`?

Comment: It should definitely work fine. Can you show how you are calling the method, and using the return value?

Comment: Because it's a smilie.

Comment: System.out.println(extractTicketEventId(extractInvalidEmailAddress("asdasdasdasdasdadasdsad<hello@yellow.com>asdasdasdasdasd")));

Comment: Your `asdasd...` are not UTF-8. It should work regardless.

Comment: my pattern is working in regex tester, but not in java, what is going on?

Comment: Using RegEx seems a bit extreme for extracting text between `<` and `>`, don't you think? I believe using `substring(int, int)` and `indexOf(char)` would be more appropriate.

Comment: @Ikthiander Did you check that it isn't the other method `extractTicketEventId` which returns `null`? This method works.

Comment: please show how you are calling the method

Comment: Just tested your method as is with the given input and it's working fine. There's a problem somewhere else, please provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: If this is in a complicated class try stubbing this method out into a simple test class, where the main method is only calling this. Eliminating as many variables as possible sometimes makes debugging easier. Make certain when you compile any previous .class files are removed to ensure you have the most current.

Comment: It is certainly not the `extractInvalidEmailAddress()` method that is returning `null`, it is possible that `extractTicketEventId()` is the method returning the `null`.

Comment: You really should check the return value of `matcher.find()` in your code.

Comment: What input is the `extractTicketEventId()` method expecting, `<hello@yellow.com>` or just `hello@yellow.com`?

Answer (score 2):

It should have worked. Can you try this 1 liner method which does same job as your longer code:

```
private String extractInvalidEmailAddress(String message) {
    return message.replaceAll("^.*?(<[^>]*>).*$", "$1");
}
```

Comment: Making your code 1 line isn't necessarily a good thing: readability vs functionality

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<.*?>");
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, this method is correct. You seem to be passing a null value to this method. I would set a debug point to find out what is happening in your application.